# How native library be executed in Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, dalvik

I am thinking about when an android application load a native library, how the library be executed?
The dex file in apk is executed by the dalvik VM, but when the logic in OPcodes calls a method in a library(not in dex format), does the VM suspend and wait for the process(that this app & VM is running on) to execute the library?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call the native library through JNI. you could read more from here about how JNI works:

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/jniTOC.html

Comment: Thanks, but I mean how the library be executed? (in another thread or something?) the native libraries are compiled into binary format(which should be executed directly on the cpu), but not in the dex format, so the dalvik vm can not interpret it. I think this should be the same situation as in JVM?

Comment: I can not be sure, but from the document, Delvim is using the same mechanism. The native code is executed in the native thread within the same address space, but it is invoked by the JVM, and it will handle all the context preparation, data formatting stuff. There are certain constraints with writing multiple thread JNI code (like local reference can not be passed etc.) , I can not recall everything unless you have specific question. :)

Comment: Thanks, this is almost what I want to know.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the good example How to build native Code and use it
http://www.aton.com/android-native-libraries-for-java-applications/